# MySql query bringing null value when data actually exists

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that will returns student name, admission number, term and class label from 5 tables using join. The code runs correctly on phpmyadmin. But when I run the script on my webapp, it returns a null value.

I have other queries on the same page that are working well except this query.

the query is shown below:

```
SELECT sr.ID, sr.name as student_name, sr.admission_number as student_no, se.label as Term, ys.label as classLabel 
FROM wpi4_wlsm_student_records as sr 
JOIN wpi4_wlsm_sections as se ON se.ID = sr.section_id 
JOIN wpi4_wlsm_sessions as ss ON ss.ID = sr.session_id 
JOIN wpi4_wlsm_class_school as cs ON cs.ID = se.class_school_id 
JOIN wpi4_wlsm_classes as ys ON ys.ID = cs.class_id 
WHERE cs.school_id = 1 AND ss.ID = 1 AND cs.class_id = '20'
GROUP BY sr.ID ORDER BY sr.roll_number ASC, sr.name ASC
```

Comment: What value does table have? Where's the PHP code you are running? Also you are getting back `NULL` as string, empty return for column, or something else?

Comment: how are you running the query in php. show us the code that returns null...